# How to test vue router beforeRouteUpdate navigation guard?

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils

First off, I'm using Vue-property-decorator.
My component has a component route, defined like this.

```
@Component({
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, _from, next) {
    const { checkInDate, checkOutDate, items, currency, locale } = to.query;
    const queryFullfilled = !!checkInDate && !!checkOutDate && !!items.length && !!currency && !!locale;

    if ([BOOKING_PAGE, RESERVATION_PAGE].indexOf(to.name) > -1 && queryFullfilled) {
      this.validateRooms();
    }
    next();
  }
})
export default class Layout extends Vue {}
```

What do I need to do in my specs in order to cover what goes on in beforeRouteUpdate?  I've googled this and people are pointing calling `wrapper.vm.$options.beforeRouteUpdate.call()`... that didn't work for me.

Has anyone done this before? Any code samples I can look at?

Thanks in advance.
John.

Comment: How about console logging whatever data you are manipulating and if needed add another route life-cycle event and log there to compare

Comment: @Michael. I know the beforeRouteUpdate works because when I load the component in the browser, I am getting the results I expect.  I see it visually.

My question is more around how I can test it in my unit tests.  How, in my unit test, do I trigger beforeRouteUpdate?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still looking for an answer following code will work.

```
const beforeRouteUpdate = wrapper.vm.$options.beforeRouteUpdate[0];
let nextFun = jest.fn();

// in place wrapper.vm you can send any object you want bcz when we call beforeRouteUpdate it looses this context

beforeRouteUpdate.call(wrapper.vm , "toObj", "fromObj", nextFun);
```

[how to call beforeRouteUpdate github](https://github.com/mcibique/vue-testing-examples#beforerouteenter)

Comment: This approach does only work if using Vue-property-decorator. Can't reproduce it when Vue-property-decorator is not present. Fosizzle's solution helped me.

Answer (score 2):

```
import component from '@/components/component'

const wrapper = shallowMount() 
// any additional setup

const to = {}
const from = {}
const next = jest.fn()
await component.beforeRouteLeave.call(wrapper.vm, to, from, next)

// asserts
expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false)
```

The route guard can be accessed through the component class. Pass in the `vm` of the instance so you have access to `this` .

Comment: The above approach is GOOD for unit testing, where the router is not part of the mounted solution. Well done.